# References about lower semi-continuous functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm learning about lower semi-continuous functionals in metric spaces. Where can I find some basic results about it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good place to start: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-7643-7357-1_7